# Printing variables in PHP the difference between these two methods?

Tags: php, variables, echo

I’m learning to program in PHP and I learned that I can print variables with text through different methods but I have a question:

What is the difference between `echo $var1 . ' ' . $var2` and `echo "{$var1} {$var2}"` in PHP? And what to use?

I don’t understand why do we have use curly brackets and even if it is another method what is the difference between the two.

Thank You!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between single-quoted and double-quoted strings in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php)

Comment: One is called concatenation and the other is called the complex (curly) syntax.

Comment: No, I know the difference between double quotes and single quotes I just don’t understand why do I need to put curly brackets

Comment: But what’s the difference between the complex syntax and the concatenation?

Comment: For those variables you don't need the curly braces, it'll work just fine without them. They're useful only when you're displaying a more "complex" variable, like `$foo->property['something']`. See https://3v4l.org/bRtiU

Comment: Can you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first method is the concatenation method and is straightforward.
The second method:
you can print variables inside double quotation marks like

  `echo " $var1 $var2 ";`

but what if you want to print something directly b/w, before, or after a variable. e.g:

`echo " $var1SomeOtherTextNotFromVariable$var2SomeMoreText ";`

PHP will assume that all text as variable until another $ is reached.
To solve this you need to tell PHP where does variable start and end. e.g:

`echo " {$var1}SomeOtherTextNotFromVariable{$var2}SomeMoreText ";`

**Note**
Please check **Progrock's** answer for another benefit of using curly braces.

Answer (score 1):

Per your comment:

> No, I know the difference between double quotes and single quotes I just don’t understand why do I need to put curly brackets

You don't "***need***" curly brackets but they can help in reading your interpolated string.

Please do not do this in your code but consider:

```
<?php
$hi = 'h';
$hii = 'sh';

echo "$hiie";
```

Do you get `hie` or `she` as the result?

Answer: neither, you get

> **Notice**: Undefined variable: hiie

To fix this then you need to be explicit with one of the following lines:

```
echo "{$hi}ie"; // hie
echo "{$hii}e"; // she
```

Answer (score 1):

(Not an answer but worthy of consideration.)

Curlies are useful if you are dealing with arrays:

```
$foo =
[
    'name' => 'Foo',
    'age'  => 23
];

echo "Name: {$foo['name']}, Age: {$foo['age']}\n";
```

Output:

```
Name: Foo, Age: 23
```

If you omit the curlies you get an error like:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting '-' or identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in ...
```